# Angular: inject generic service in child component

Tags: angular

I have tow components using one child component which has to use tow deferent services depend on the parent:

```
export class ParentComponent1 {
 @ViewChild('childComponent', { static: true })
  public childComponent: ChildComponent<Service1>;
}

export class ParentComponent2 {
 @ViewChild('childComponent', { static: true })
  public childComponent: ChildComponent<Service2>;
}

Service1 extends MyService {};
Service2 extends MyService {};

export class ChildComponent<S extends MyService> {
constructor(private service S){}
}
```

**Error:  This type does not have a value, so it cannot be used as an injection token.**

I don't know how to make angular choose the service that I want to inject.

I can inject both services and choose between them based on a parameter, but I look for a clean solution if you have any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389852/is-there-a-way-to-inject-a-service-into-a-component-from-the-parent-component

Comment: Yes, perfect thank you so much Ashot (y)

Comment: no problem, glad to help